# Minimum distance metric on encoded sequence

Tags: algorithm, encryption, statistics, metrics

I'm looking for a **minimum distance metric** which preserve subsequences subtitution. With this I mean that any subsequence of second sequence can have different representation, but still be same to the first subsequence. The two sequences will always have same the length. I'm familiar with Hamming or Levenshtein distance, but they are probably useless in this case.

Consider this examples:

```
AABBAA
CCDDCC
```

has distance 0, because `A = C` and `B = D` (or `AA = CC` and `BB = DD`).

```
AABBBBBB
CCDDEEEE
```

has distance 2, because `A = C` and `B = E` (or `AA = CC` or `BB = EE` or `BBBB = EEEE`), but the `B =/= D` (or `BB =/= DD`).

However, this function may not behave exactly like that. **I just need to know how unencoded sequence is similar, in term of repetition, to encoded one.** You could assume that second sequence is encoded with something like caesar cipher (although I'm not sure if i.e the shift could vary through the time).

*Note:*

I also thought about compressing the two sequences with LZW algorithm and compare their compression ratio. Any other idea?

Comment: Can't make much sense from this description.

Answer (score 0):

You can enumerate elements in your sequences with continuous numbers from the beginning and then use Levenshtein distance or something like that.

```
AACCAABB  --> 11221133  (A->1, C->2, B->3)
CCXXCCYY  --> 11221133  (C->1, X->2, Y->3)

d(AACCAABB, CCXXCCYY) = d(11221133, 11221133) = 0
```